# How to determine Stackdepth required for individual task to create using FreeRTOS xTaskCreate?

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, freertos

I am using FreeRTOS to develop Firmware on STM32 MCU.

What are the techniques I can use to determine stack size required for individual task which is created using FreeRTOS xTaskCreate API?

I know this depends on work done by individual task but I need to know how can I find out nearby stackdepth value to make sure my Task will work without any stack overflow error during runtime.

Comment: Have you read the official [FAQ](https://www.freertos.org/FAQMem.html#StackSize) ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a FreeRTOS aware IDE plug-in that tells you the stack usage.  Failing that, you can calculate it - or get GCC to calculate it for you - but my preference is a bit more pragmatic.  First ensure you have a [stack overflow hook](https://www.freertos.org/Stacks-and-stack-overflow-checking.html) defined, in case the stack is too small.  Then assign a stack you think is too large, let the code execute through what is assume to be the highest stack usage code path, then call [uxStackGetHighWaterMark()](https://www.freertos.org/uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark.html) to see how much stack was actually used and adjust accordingly - remembering to add anything necessary for whatever the likely interrupt nesting stack usage will be.  You can also use more invasive functions such as [uxTaskGetSystemStack()](https://www.freertos.org/uxTaskGetSystemState.html) to see the stack usage of all tasks.